# How do I create a collection without a running Solr?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm trying to automatically bootstrap a SolrCloud cluster. I've figured out how to upload my configuration files and my solr.xml file to zookeeper using

```
./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost ${ZK_HOST} -cmd bootstrap -solrhome ${SOLR_HOME}
./bin/solr zk cp -z ${ZK_HOST} ${SOLR_HOME}/solr.xml zk:/solr.xml
```

But what I don't understand is how to create my collection before any of the Solr servers have finished starting up yet.

I've tried using [zkcli.sh](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/1d85cd783863f75cea133fb9c452302214165a4d/solr/solr-ref-guide/src/command-line-utilities.adoc#link-a-collection-to-a-configset) to link my configuration to a collection, but this requires the collection to already exist.

I've also tried using [bin/solr create](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/solr-control-script-reference.html#create-a-core-or-collection) to create the collection and link it to my configuration but that requires Solr to be already running.

Is it not possible to create a SolrCloud collection before you have the entire cluster running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You need Solr running, you hit this [Collections api endpoint](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/collections-api.html#create) to create the collection. And this endpoint is served by Solr

This question was recently discussed on the [solr-user mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/febc454a9e3589858905c46210894ce056a52a849131f7860d62abd2@%3Csolr-user.lucene.apache.org%3E) and the conclusion was the same, you need to have Solr running in order to create a collection.

One suggestion to work around this limitation is to write a script that waits for the appropriate number of nodes to become available before calling the collections API endpoint to create the collection. An example [python script](https://github.com/apache/incubator-sdap-nexus/blob/91b15ce0b123d652eaa1f5eb589a835ae3e77ceb/docker/solr/cloud-init/create-collection.py) is mentioned in the email thread that is capable of doing this.

Comment: I was incredulous that this was actually the answer but my own research confirmed that this is the case. I've edited in the details I found to your answer, hope you don't mind.